# ASCII issues in SQL Server table export

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ascii, non-ascii-characters

I recently had an issue with an SSIS package where it failed to export the data in a SQL table.  I was able to narrow down the problem to a record which contained a strange character in one field.  The field was CUST_NAME and the value in it was:

GUY & O�NEILL, INC.

Of course, the question mark inside the diamond should have been an apostrophe.

Is there any way to track these sort of strange characters using a query?  I'd want to search the whole table, but for *all* "out of the ordinary" characters.  I have no idea where to even start.

Comment: What is an "out of the ordinary" character?

Comment: @Larnu - Basically, anything you wouldn't expect.  Like that weird diamond.  I don't know what other weird characters might show up, because I definitely wasn't expecting that one.

Comment: That could be *anything*. The above looks like a name, for example, so I wouldn't expect a number. So would `LIKE '%[^A-z ]%'` work? That will, of course, also flag due to the comma and the period.

Comment: @larnu - Well, I'd expect numbers, some punctuation (i.e. "O'Neill" or "Catch 21") would be within the realm of a customer name, but definitely not a square or a diamond.  I'm trying to think what other symbols I've seen that aren't within the normal ASCII values.  Basically, anything that might trip up an SSIS package trying to export data to a CSV file.

Comment: Such a character wouldn't "trip up" an SSIS package though. SSIS supports `nvarchar` data using the `WSTR` datatype.

Comment: The square/diamond symbol is likely the program you are using attempting to render a character it doesn't have in the font(or something weird like that). Grab a hex editor (I'm a fan of XVI32) and see what the value is for the diamond and then consult your favorite ascii table website. Given the position in the supplied string, it's a smart single quote `’` https://www.ascii-code.com/CP1252/146  vs the normal single quote `'` https://www.ascii-code.com/character/'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found some code that does what I need.  For anyone who might have a similar issue, I used this code:

```
SELECT
    CASE_NUMBER,
    ACCOUNT_FULL_NAME,
    patindex('%[^ !-~]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN,ACCOUNT_FULL_NAME) as [Position],
    substring(ACCOUNT_FULL_NAME,patindex('%[^ !-~]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN,ACCOUNT_FULL_NAME),1) as [InvalidCharacter],
    ascii(substring(ACCOUNT_FULL_NAME,patindex('%[^ !-~]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN,ACCOUNT_FULL_NAME),1)) as [ASCIICode]
FROM [dbo].[CLNT_SVC_GOLD_SURVEY_EMAILS_WEEKLY]
WHERE patindex('%[^ !-~]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN,ACCOUNT_FULL_NAME) >0
```

It provided me with the following output:

```
CASE_NUMBER ACCOUNT_FULL_NAME       Position    InvalidCharacter    ASCIICode
02884401    GUY & O�NEILL, INC.        8        �                     63
```